# Where to put code that loads products from cookie?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, session-state, microsoft-commerce-server

We have a project which is Sharepoint solution combined with Commerce Server. It's a webshop, and we are currently installing a feature where the products but in the basket is stored using cookies.

We are doing that by adding all the products guids + quantity in a cookie file.

However, where to load the users basket on their next visit?

On a normal asp.net website I would use Global.asax -> Session_start, but as far as I can tell, there are no Global.asax in a Sharepoint solution.

So my question is: Is there any way to react on the session_start event in Sharepoint? Or are there other events/ways which are more appropriate? I am not really much into Sharepoint, so any help is gladly accepted!

Comment: Bad way to store all that on cookie. Keep the selection on the database, not on cookie, and connect the cookie with the database.

Comment: Great point - but we still have to do the load somewhere :-) Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up putting the code in the webpart for the shopping basket. This is a pretty good solution as it exists on every page on the website.

I would prefer putting the code in a HttpModule, but setting that up in Sharepoint is pretty annoying.. Also it is more error prune than just putting the code in the shopping basket.